# Specifying more than one selector when when changing classes in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I specify more than one selector using `data`

I currently do with only one, but would like to add another one in there. Seems like it won't work.

```
$('.user[data-id="'+jsonId+'"]').removeClass('hide').addClass('no-hide');
```

I'd like to use a second one in there like this:

```
$('.user[data-id="'+jsonId+'"]'+user[data-country="'+jsonCountry+'"]').removeClass('hide').addClass('no-hide');
```

They both belong to the same link, like this:

```
<a data-id ="jason" data-country="se">Hide</a>
```

So I'm trying to change the class where `data-id=jsonId and data-country=jasonCountry`

Comment: That link doesn't appear to have a `class="user"`, I'm presuming it's supposed to?

Comment: I will. I copied in haste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you would concatenate both attribute selector strings:

```
$('.user[data-id="'+jsonId+'"][data-country="'+jsonCountry+'"]').removeClass('hide').addClass('no-hide');
```

Comment: +1. Link - [Multiple Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine like this,

```
$('.user[data-id="'+jsonId+'"][data-country="'+jsonCountry+'"]').removeClass('hide').addClass('no-hide');
```